# How do I zoom/Pan to a Leaflet Map, such that the given point is off-center?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zoom, offset

In my Leaflet Application, on some event, I want to zoom to a particular marker, and then show it's popup. I have certain other custom components on top of the map, and the Popup that appears, is hidden behind these components.

This could be resolved, if I could zoom/pan to the map, such that the given point (i.e. location of marker) is not in the center, but  slightly lower.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been discussed in this Issue: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/859

Based on the code given there, I wrote the following two functions:

```
L.Map.prototype.panToOffset = function (latlng, offset, options) {
    var x = this.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng).x - offset[0]
    var y = this.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng).y - offset[1]
    var point = this.containerPointToLatLng([x, y])
    return this.setView(point, this._zoom, { pan: options })
}

L.Map.prototype.setViewOffset = function (latlng, offset, targetZoom) {
    var targetPoint = this.project(latlng, targetZoom).subtract(offset),
    targetLatLng = this.unproject(targetPoint, targetZoom);
    return this.setView(targetLatLng, targetZoom);
}
```

Now these functions can be called as follows:

```
map.panToOffset(e.target.getLatLng(),[0,100], {"animate":true});
//or if you want to zoom to
map.setViewOffset(e.target.getLatLng(),[0,100],9);
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in those Leaflet plugins:

- [Leaflet-active-area](https://github.com/Mappy/Leaflet-active-area): This plugin allows you to use a smaller portion of the map as an active area. All positioning methods (setView, fitBounds, setZoom) will be applied on this portion instead of the all map.
- [Leaflet.ControlledBounds](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.ControlledBounds): Inspired by Leaflet-active-area, automatically detects the largest area of the map not covered by any map controls and applies setView, fitBounds, setZoom, getBounds to that area.

Answer (score 0):

The amazing answer by @Devdatta didn't directly work with me in Angular. I'm doing this based on his answer.

```
    // Center on Popup Open with Offset
    map.on('popupopen', (e) => {
        // Center Map with Offset
        const targetPoint = map.project(e.target._popup._latlng, e.target._zoom).subtract(MAP_POPUP_OFFSET),
            targetLatLng = map.unproject(targetPoint, e.target._zoom);
        map.setView(targetLatLng, e.target._zoom);
        // Events listeners (must use => to access "this")
        addDeviceControlEventListener(this.elementRef, this.ngZone, this.router);
    });
```

The `MAP_POPUP_OFFSET` is just

```
const MAP_POPUP_OFFSET = new L.Point(0, 100);
```